# What object a menuitem action triggered segue should be called on?

Tags: macos, cocoa, segue, action, menuitem

I have a menuitem selection triggered segue you can see on the attached pictures

[image]

The NSMeniItem connections:

[image]

The segue it triggers:

[image]

How can I trigger the segue programmatically.
It has an identifier, it's ok. 
But what object on I have to call the

> - (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender;

Comment: If you don't use the sender parameter in `prepareForSegue` you can pass `nil`

Comment: I would call it with sender:nil of course, the question is, the object I have to send the  performSegueWithIdentifier message  
[whatObjectToUseHere performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openSettingsWindow" sender:nil];

Comment: To the view controller which is going to perform the segue (`self`)

Comment: there is no view controller at that stage, this would be the first window, no open window yet, no window controller yet, the menu is the main menu in the main.storyboard

Comment: in that case I have to rephrase the question, how can I get a reference to the settings windowcontroller from the main.storyboard if it is not the initial controller?

Comment: Is the application a menu bar app without a main window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144203/discussion-between-hofi-and-vadian).

Answer (score 0):

@vadian pointed me out that I need the windowcontroller the segue should be called on first and I can get it like this

```
let mainStoryBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
windowController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Preferences") as! NSWindowController
windowController.showWindow(self)
```

where 
windowController is a property in AppDelegate
"Preferences" is the identifier in the Storyboard

it has benefit of getting a reference to the window controller itself

as I did not need the reference currently just wanted to trigger the segue i stayed with the following solution

```
[NSApp sendAction:mPreferencesMenuItem.action to:mPreferencesMenuItem.target from:mPreferencesMenuItem];
```

where mPreferencesMenuItem is the menuitem that triggers the segue

Answer (score 0):

`NSViewController` and `NSWindowController` conforms to the `NSSeguePerforming` protocol. So in your controller subclass you can call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender];`